# How can i read back an object stored in a session?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables, data-persistence

First of all, here comes the load part.

```
Structure MainStruct
        Dim Ans1 As String
        Dim Ans2 As String
 End Structure


Dim Build As New List(Of MainStruct)
...
...
...

Session("MyData") = Build
```

The question is how can i read back the contents of the list, stored in the Session?
I mean something like...

```
Build = Session("MyData")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Build = Session("MyData").Ans1` you will want to do

```
Build = CType(Session("MyData"), List(Of MainStruct))
```

You could also do a `DirectCast` instead of `CType` if you want.

**Edit: to question change**

To then read back the results you will be able to go through Build.

You could loop through it with a for each, a for, some linq, whatever you want!

Answer (score 1):

Since its VB i dont think u need to cast it back, correct me if im wrong.

i dont think u can just do

> Build = Session("MyData").Ans1

You need to do something like:

> Build = Session("MyData")

then u iterate though ur List<> to access the structs

Comment: It depends on what compiler options are set.  If you're using Option Strict as you should be, you will need the cast.